# How to Resolve AWS Elastic Beanstalk Deploy Error

Tags: visual-studio-2008, amazon-web-services, windows-server-2008

I created a simple test website in VS 2008 using the AWS Web Project template. The only modification I made to the default template was to add an asmx Web Service (my real need is to implement WCF, so asmx is just included for now as a simplified test).  When I try to AWS Publish this project, I receive the errors: **Responses from myinstance-id were received but the commands failed. (and) Failed to deploy application.**

The AWS Publish status is "Environment is healthy", with Container type: 64bit Windows Server 2008 R2 running IIS 7.5

The beanstalk instance security rules (in test) are as follows:

Port 80, Protocol: tcp, Source: 0.0.0.0/0
Port 80, Protocol: tcp, Source: sg-999999
Port 3389, Protocol: tcp, Source: 0.0.0.0/0

**Notes:** 
1) The AWS Environment includes 1 ECS instance and 1 RDS MySQL instance.
2) The security groups include an rds-association.
3) The Publish log is voluminous and does not appear to to contain any useful info.

My local Windows Firewall includes Inbound and Outbound rules for ports 80 and 3389.

I have been grappling with this for two days now and my searches have not uncovered any relevant help.

I get the feeling this is an AWS firewall issue, but I would very much appreciate any assistance or document references that point to a resolution of this issue; or in other words, “How do I get Jack to climb the beanstalk?”

TIA

**ADDED: AWS LOG Message**

EventLog Application:

2013-06-14T17:59:10.000Z Information 2:(2) MSDTC 2 - The description for Event ID '1073746026' in Source 'MSDTC 2' cannot be found.  The local computer may not have the necessary registry information or message DLL files to display the message, or you may not have permission to access them.  The following information is part of the event:'0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'Mutual Authentication Required', 'NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService', '0', '0', '1'
2013-06-14T17:59:02.000Z Warning 0:(0) Microsoft-Windows-User Profiles Service - Windows detected your registry file is still in use by other applications or services. The file will be unloaded now. The applications or services that hold your registry file may not function properly afterwards.

Comment: Does your application respond with a 200 on port 80 from localhost? The deployment does a loopback healthcheck, which, if it fails can cause the error message you see. You can also check the logs in c:\cfn\logs for more clues about what went wrong.

Comment: A Windows Update rebooted my laptop and I was able to redeploy the web app without error. I must be a bit thick, but I am confused as to how to open a web page from the app. When I click the Url (http://wstest.elasticbeanstalk.com) I just get a standard IIS 7.5 web page and when I try to reference the app. by appending (/AWS_Web_App1) I get a 404 error. What am I missing?

Comment: That inidicates that your app didn't get deployed correctly. If you snapshot the logs, there may be some clues as to why.

Comment: Using paping, I was able to determine port 80 is operational, but I cannot find cfn\logs anywhere on c:?

Comment: I recreated a new environment and posted the message at the top of the snapshot log - omitting the voluminous detail. I cannot find anything to clearly explain what it means or how to resolve it.

Comment: It seems very odd that there's no c:\cfn folder on an instance created by Beanstalk. Are you using a custom AMI in your deployment?

Comment: No. This was such a long time ago, I barely remember it. As I recollect, I concluded it was a AWS Windows bug, which has probably been fixed by now.  It was so frustrating, I now use manual means to deploy / update AWS applications.

Answer (score 1):

A possible reason for a deployment error on Elastic Beanstalk is specifying an AWSAccessKey and AWSSecretKey key-values in the application settings deployment option. Regardless whether they have valid or invalid values, a simple test asp.net website might have deployment errors if they are specified (and will).

You can remove them (and fix the deployment error) by going to the Elastic Beanstalk console, picking the application environment -> Configuration -> Environment Properties and removing these optional properties.